# Split a line of (R-) markdown code in a table definition

Tags: r-markdown, markdown

I would like to maintain a sensible line width in a markdown
code that embeds some table definitions. But as I understand
in a table each rendered line is defined by a line of code

```
|   | col 1 | col 2  | col 3 | col 4 | col 5 | col 6 | col 7 | col 8 | col 9 | col 10 | col 11 |
|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|
| Problem | I | find | this | row | somewhat too | long | to match | my | own | coding | standard |
```

To be more precise, my problem is for Rmarkdown code containing tables
with some LaTeX code embeded such as `$\mathbf{X}\boldsymbol{\beta}$`. In some cases I would appreciate to use one line of markdown code to define a single cell.

I am aware that this is nearly a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53896668/8836534), but I suspect that a Rmarkdown code could generate a correct github markdown and still maintain some flexibility.